# Momentum conservation during electron-positron anihilation

Tags: waves, momentum, mass-energy, antimatter, matter

If the electron is standing still and the positron is moving the cancelation produces two photons that should conserve the particles momentum. So what direction should move the photon that conserves the momentum of the particle that was standing still? The only thing I can figure out is that the two photons should have different wavelengths...

Comment: Consider the positron moves in positive $x$-direction. Have you considered that the photons could *both* also move in positive $x$-direction, but in opposite directions regarding a direction perpendicular to $x$ (let's call it $y$)? (Meaning the combined paths of the positron plus the paths of the two photons look like the letter Y)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here - what does *"that conserves the momentum of the particle that was standing still"* mean? It is *total* momentum that is conserved in collisions, not the momentum of individual particles.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine yourself in the center of mass of both particles. It's clear that both photons must have equal energies and opposite momenta. That's why in the frame which you ask about in your question both photons have different wavelenghts.